# Plotting 2nd order ODE solution for specific values of constants

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Suppose that I have a 2nd order, linear ODE and I want to plot the solution I found using [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html). How can I plot giving specific values of `C[1]` and `C[2]`. Let's say I want to plot the solutions for `C[1]={1,3,4}` and `C[2]={1,3}`. That makes 6 solutions which I want to plot.

I give this specific example:

```
eq = y''[x] - 3 y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 7 Sin[4 x];

solution = DSolve[eq, y[x], x]
(* {{y[x] -> 
   E^x C[1] + E^(2 x) C[2] + 7/170 (6 Cos[4 x] - 7 Sin[4 x])}} *)

yy = solution[[1, 1, 2]]
(* E^x C[1] + E^(2 x) C[2] + 7/170 (6 Cos[4 x] - 7 Sin[4 x]) *)
```

How can I make a list of partial solutions giving some specific values that I choose for `C[1]` and `C[2]`, let's name it partialsolutions which I later will plot using `Plot[partialsolutions, {x,-5,5}]` for example.

Comment: This is your second question, head to the help centre and read about proper code formatting practices and format your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expression = E^x C[1] + E^(2 x) C[2] + 7/170 (6 Cos[4 x] - 7 Sin[4 x]);

c1list = {.01, .04, .06}; c2list = {.001, .002};
funcs = Flatten@ Table[expression /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, {i, c1list}, {j, c2list}];

Plot[funcs, {x, 3, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

You can also do:

```
replacements = Table[{C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, {i, c1list}, {j, c2list}]
Plot[Evaluate[expression /. replacements], {x, 3, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
(* same picture *)
```